# Again about typesetting principal value integrals

Tags: unicode-math

Unicode-math provides `\fint` and `\intbar` symbols which can be used to typeset Princpal value of an integral. Unfortunately these symbols do not scale up as standard `\int` does as the followng example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{Cambria}
    \setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Corbel}
    \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont[Color=000066,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria Math}
\else
    \usepackage{esint}
\fi

\begin{document}
\[
  \displaystyle      A\int B 
  \textstyle         A\int B 
  \scriptstyle       A\int B 
  \scriptscriptstyle A\int B 
\]

\[
  \displaystyle      A\fint B 
  \textstyle         A\fint B 
  \scriptstyle       A\fint B 
  \scriptscriptstyle A\fint B 
\]
\end{document}
```

How to device a macro from `\fint` or `\intbar` to device a functionally equivalent of `\int`? I am aware about other solutions providing commands to typeset principal value integral but they all need fine tuning after change of math OTF font.

Comment: Why did you make it more difficult to test your example by removing the preamble?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I updated the question.

Comment: Did you see the posting [The Principal Value Integral symbol](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-prinvalint.html) in the UK TeX FAQ collection?

Comment: @Mico although that answer predates opentype math fonts by a decade or two:-)

Comment: @Mico: As I said, the solution from UK TeX FAQ needs different tuning (`\kern-.5\wd0`) for different fonts.

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked that part.

Answer (score 4):

`unicode-math` defines the two characters in the same way, whether the symbol is available in multiple sizes is purely a choice of the font designer.

With stix (xits) I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}

\[
  \displaystyle      A\int B 
  \textstyle         A\int B 
  \scriptstyle       A\int B 
  \scriptscriptstyle A\int B 
\]

\[
  \displaystyle      A\fint B 
  \textstyle         A\fint B 
  \scriptstyle       A\fint B 
  \scriptscriptstyle A\fint B 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actially it means that Cambria Math is buggy.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov of course the version of your question that i answered above didn't even mention cambria:-) latin modern also doesn't scale fint

Comment: So my question should be reformulates as How can I scale up `\fint` symbol in case of Latim Modern and Cambria Math assuming that XITS Math, STIX Math and Asana Math are not suitable for some reason.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov ideal (long term) answer would be to ask the font maintainers to fix the metrics of the variant integrals to match the standard integral sign, but a more pragmatic answer might be to take the uktug faq and just tweak the spacing for each font