# How might I produce a, ‘Horizontally Stricken-through Integral Sign’?

Tags: symbols

I would like to be able to produce an altered integral sign, such that it becomes a ‘Horizontally Stricken-through Integral Sign’.

I have had a look at various commands, `\st`, `\hcancel` etc. but none of these seems appropriate.

The symbol I would like is shown, approximately, just below.
[image: Horizontally Stricken-through Integral Sign]

Comment: Could you hand-draw an image of what you seek and upload it here please?

Comment: Are you inquring about the Principal Value integral symbol? If so, take a look at [this webpage](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint).

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am actually, I did not know the symbol was a notation for a Cauchy principal value integral.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was solved in a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Again about typesetting principal value integrals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336341/again-about-typesetting-principal-value-integrals)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\[\fint\frac{dz}{z-1}\]
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}
\[\fint\frac{dz}{z-1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]